# Setters based on array Index in Java

Tags: java, setter, getter-setter

I have the following:

```
public class  Car{
public Car()
{//some stuff
}
private Car [] carmodels  ;
public Car [] getCarModel() {
return this.carmodels;
}

public void setcarModel(Car [] carmodels ) {
this.carmodels = carmodels;

}
```

Now on my test class, I have something like this

```
public void main (String [] args)
 {
   Car car1= new Car();
   car.setcarModel(new Car[5]);//here i create an array of Car

   for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
   {
    // how can i created 5 cars and set them based on index i
    // car.setCarModel[new Car()]????
   }
 }
```

How can do that? I could use a temp array of type Car which I can pass to my Setter just after the loop. But is there a better way?

Comment: what is your goal? add 5 new cars to car1's carmodels?

Comment: That is exactly my goal; without the use of a temp array of type Car

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a setter that accepts an index:

```
public void setCarModel(int index, Car carModel) {
    this.cardmodels[index] = carModel;
}
```

Then, inside your loop, call

```
car.setCarModel(i, new Car());
```

Comment: How does the array know what size it needs to?(how many indexes it needs). it's been a while i used java but if I remember correctly arrays are fixed size.

Comment: @SvenB Apparently its size is fixed to 5.

Answer (score 3):

See the method `getCarModel`? That method returns a `Car[]` right? That means you can do anything you can do on an array on `car1.getCarModel()`!

So how do you set an item at an index of an array? You do this:

```
someArray[someIndex] = someValue;
```

If we apply this to the array returned by `car1.getCarModel`,

```
car1.getCarModel()[i] = new Car();
```

That's the way to do it.

Alternatively, you ca write another method in `Car` that sets an item in the car models array:

```
public void setItemInCarModels(int index, Car item) {
    carModels[index] = item;
}
```

Simple!

Btw, your model makes no sense...

Answer (score 2):

If you insist on not using a temp value in the for loop you could use an [ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) instead of an array for the carmodels.

than add a method

```
public void addCar(Car toadd)
{
     carmodels.add(toadd);
}
```

than in your foor loop just call

```
for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
{
    car.addCar(new Car());
 }
```

Im assuming the size can vary and that a fixed size array is not sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
{
  car.getCarModel()[i] =new Car();
}
```

or

Write another overloaded setter by passing index.

```
public void setCarModel(int index, Car c)
{
 carmodels[index] = c;
}

for(int i =0;i<5;i++)
{
   car.setCarModel(i, new Car());
}
```